# Rekognition add identifier for user face being added to a collection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm using Rekognition for face authentication.

When I register a user I have

1. their user id
2. multiple photos of that user

How can I associate/label all those photos with that id when indexing/adding their faces to a collection?

When I search by face in a collection I want to be able to get back their id.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that `ExternalImageId` does the job fine. It can be used for many different images. The docs made it sound like it wouldn't re-index something with the same ExternalImageId but it seems that that is only the case if you provide an identical image.

```
response = rekognition.index_faces(
    CollectionId=group_id,
    Image={
        'Bytes': base64.b64decode(face.encode('utf-8'))
    },
    ExternalImageId=user_id,
    DetectionAttributes=[
        'DEFAULT',
    ]
)
```

Although, it is worth mentioning that `ExternalImageId` is for the image, not the face. In my case it is ok because I crop the face first. But if you want to identify multiple users in the face you will probably have to save each of the returned faceIds in a DB in order to identify your user later on.